# Enable/Disable checkBox based on combobox value with ternary operator

Tags: c#, winforms, conditional-operator

I'm trying to enable checkbox based on comboxbox selection. I am aware that with simple if  condtion can solve my problem but when i change it to ternary operator it shows error

```
if (ComboBox.SelectedValue.Equals(enum.value))
{
    chkbox.Enabled = false;
}
else 
{ 
    chkbox.Enabled = true; 
}
```

Ternary:

```
ComboBox.SelectedValue == enum.value ? chkbox.Enabled = false : chkbox.Enabled = true;
```

This works fine but when i changed it to ternary it throws errors. How can i change it to make it work

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ternary syntax is incorrect. It should be like this instead:

```
chkbox.Enabled = ComboBox.SelectedValue == enum.value ? false : true;
```

You could also write it like this:

```
chkbox.Enabled = ComboBox.SelectedValue != enum.value;
```